# PyTest conftest.py incorrectly shows the directory os.getcwd() in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

When I use a fixture using a file conftest.py the directory I get through the os.getcwd() is not correct! I get C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_60 \ jre \ bin
If I run the test from the command line, everything works correctly
Example:

conftest.py

```
import os
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def curdir():
    directory = os.getcwd()
    print directory
    return directory
```

**PyCharm**

I get C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin

[Incorrect directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlZYQ.png)

**CMD**

I get C:\python\testing\scripts\example

[Correct directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPRjL.png)

test_simple.py

```
# coding=utf-8
import json
import os

def test_simple(curdir):
    print curdir
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve never run PyCharm on Windows and I don’t know Windows very well at all, but here’s my guess:  PyCharm (a Java application) sets the JRE’s binary directory as the current directory when it is run, and any process spawned by PyCharm (such as the Python interpreter) simply inherits this.

So I wouldn’t necessarily think that what you’re seeing is weird at all.

If you need your current directory to be something specific, you’d probably best force it by using `os.chdir()`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
It was found that this is.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead

```
os.getcwd()
```

use

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```